# Can't make table with non-standard multicolumns

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like this:

[image]

1. 1-st row: 2 columns, 50% each.
2. 2-nd row: 9 columns, sizes given.

I tried to use the approach from this answer:

[Table with non-standard multicolumns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113378/table-with-non-standard-multicolumns)

Created 10 `X` columns and united them according to scheme.

But instead of the desired outcome I got this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=0.7cm,rmargin=0.7cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |*{10}{X} }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|X}{50\%} & \multicolumn{5}{|X|}{50\%}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{12mm}}{12mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{9mm}}{9mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{17mm}}{17mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{11mm}}{11mm} &
  \multicolumn{2}{|X}{X} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{18mm}}{18mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{17mm}}{17mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|r}{r} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{r}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

How to fix?

Comment: If you want to specify the widths of all columns explictly you don't need (and should't use) `tabularx` just use `tabular` and`p` columns. as it is, the top level preamble means `X` corresponds to roughly `p(0.1\textwidth}` (ignoring tabcolsep) but your two 5 columns spans are also specified as being X so the same .1\textwidth. they could just be `c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note if you use vertical lines in multicolumns you should only use them at the *left* of an entry (except the first entry in the row which can have them either side) otherwise they will not line up correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=0.7cm,rmargin=0.7cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |m{12mm}|m{9mm}|m{17mm}|m{11mm}|X|m{18mm}|m{17mm}|r|r|}
  \hline
 \multicolumn{9}{|@{}c@{}|}{\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\hsize-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                                      {X|X}
50\% & 50\% \\
\hline
50\% & 50\% \end{tabularx}}\\
  \hline
  12mm &
  9mm &
  17mm &
 11mm &
  X &
  18mm &
  17mm &
  r &
  r\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried 2 rows in 50% table, separated by `\hline`. But there is a space between `\hline` and the borders of external table. I tried modifying the width of internal table: `\dimexpr\hsize-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep`, but it didn't help: table broke.

Comment: @user4035 in that case you just need to be a bit more careful how you distribute the tabcolsep padding, so the `\hline` gets the correct width. I updated answer with image

Answer (score 1):

```
Maybe a simple solution?

\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=0.7cm,rmargin=0.7cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |*{10}{X} }
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |*{9}{X} }
  \hline
 % \multicolumn{5}{|X}{50\%} & \multicolumn{5}{|X|}{50\%}\\
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{50\%\hfil\vline\hfil50\%\hfil } \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{12mm}}{12mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{9mm}}{9mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{17mm}}{17mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{11mm}}{11mm} &
 % \multicolumn{2}{|X}{X} &
 \multicolumn{1}{|X}{X} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{18mm}}{18mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{17mm}}{17mm} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|r}{r} &
  \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{r}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No. If you try a multiline text inside a parbox instead of 50%, it will break.